i want to display product Unit and its SKU in same row in google form
i have one requirement to show product and its Sku in same row, but am not able to find any option in google form. I mean i want to keep product 1 and its unit in same row same as for product 2 and so on in same block of question. is there any way to do



SKU
QUANTITY




LEDL050
40


VBTR01
50


HDROL01
60


HDROL0
110


GRS00
150


DNRT0
130



https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PC2Ob45JznVjyVy4W1FLsawIuvY26kvmXyOT35Aa0Is/edit
Details



SKU
QUANTITY




LEDL050
40


VBTR01
50


HDROL01
60


HDROL0
110


GRS00
150


DNRT0
130



https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PC2Ob45JznVjyVy4W1FLsawIuvY26kvmXyOT35Aa0Is/edit
Details

How is this question different  from not able to display remaining units in google form when i choose a SKU from dropdown - which I have just answered. You can't ask the same question twice in the space of 2 days; please resolve (or at least delete) the first question.

What you are asking is not possible. Google Forms has not been designed to work that way.
